# Import java.awt.Dimension error

Tags: java, android

I am just a beginner and I was trying to import dimension and they told me this "unknown type or package 'Dimension'"

Here is my code:

import java.awt.Dimension;

Comment: Are you add any jar for it ?

Comment: `java.awt` is not available on Android.

Comment: Is their any way to solve this?

Comment: The linked question explains the alternatives that you can use instead of `Dimension`.